# Async iterator ticking at a regular interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am implementing an asynchronous iterator to be used with `async for` which should return a new value at a (mostly) regular interval.

We can illustrate such iterator with a simple clock that will increment a counter every ~n seconds:

```
import asyncio

class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        self.counter = 0
        self.interval = interval
        self.tick = asyncio.Event()
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.tick_tock())

    async def tick_tock(self):
        while True:
            self.tick.clear()
            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)
            self.counter = self.__next__()
            self.tick.set()

    def __next__(self):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.counter

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        await self.tick.wait()
        return self.counter
```

Is there a better or cleaner approach than using `asyncio.Event`? More than one coroutine will `async for` on this iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your approach is fine. Note that since python 3.6, you can also use [asynchronous generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/):

```
async def clock(start=0, step=1, interval=1.):
    for i in count(start, step):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

However, you won't be able to share them between multiple coroutines. You would have to run the clock in a task and make the data available through an asynchronous iteration interface, which is essentially what you did in your code. Here's a [possible implementation](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/445651b2d5b68426a348bad88ff15430).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.6+ you can use [asynchronous generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) which are more readable.

```
async def Clock(interval=1):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        counter += 1
        yield counter


async def main():
    async for i in Clock(1):
        print(i)
        if i == 4:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

Comment: The problem is that the iterator could be used by multiple coroutines simultaneously. This is why I used `asyncio.Event`.